# Rails - I can't parse JSON response properly

Tags: ruby, json, github-api

I can't parse JSON response properly. Just showing blank page. My code is like below.

```
h = response.to_json
@data = h["items"][0]["login"]
```

JSON response

```
[
    ["total_count", 2782],
    ["incomplete_results", false],
    ["items", [{
      "login": "datomnurdin",
      "id": 5416242,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/5416242?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/datomnurdin",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false,
      "score": 1.0
    },..
```

What I want is to be like this

```
datomnurdin
```

P.S: Original response from Github API using this library,https://github.com/peter-murach/github

```
> #<Hashie::Mash avatar_url="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/5416242?v=3"
> events_url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/events{/privacy}"
> followers_url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/followers"
> following_url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/following{/other_user}" gists_url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/gists{/gist_id}"
> gravatar_id="" html_url="https://github.com/datomnurdin" id=5416242
> login="datomnurdin"
> organizations_url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/orgs"
> received_events_url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/received_events" repos_url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/repos" score=1.0
> site_admin=false
> starred_url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/starred{/owner}{/repo}" subscriptions_url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin/subscriptions"
> type="User" url="https://api.github.com/users/datomnurdin">,..
```

Comment: I really can't try from code provided.

Comment: the json response you provided is incorrect. Maybe you used `[]` instead of `{}`?

Comment: no, it's from github API.

Comment: It looks like you're hitting GitHub's search API, or something similar, which [returns a hash, not an array](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users), and somehow you've converted it. Can you show us the rest of the code that fetches `response`?

Comment: @Kristján check my edited question.

Comment: That's not quite helpful. Show us your code from `response = ...` until `h = response.to_json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github library you linked returns `Hashie::Mash` instance.

One should not try to convert the returned result to json (which is apparently a string,) just use:

```
h = result_as_returned_by_github_library
@data = h["items"][0]["login"]
```